# PyCharm - packaging_tool.py error on Install packaging tools

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to set up a Python Flask project and Project Interpreter. It showing me that "Python Packaging tools not found"

[image: Python Packaging tools not found]

When I'm trying to install it showing me Error in Line 100 of PyCharm file -

[image: Error]

```
Execute command:
/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/packaging_tool.py untar 
/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/setuptools-28.8.0.tar.gz

Error Occurred:
nstall (pkgs) : try : try : from pip._internal import main except Exception: from pip import main except ImportError: error_no_pip() return main([ 'install' ] + pkgs) def do_uninstall (pkgs) : try : try : from pip._internal import main except Exception: from pip import main except ImportError: error_no_pip() return main([ 'uninstall' , '-y' ] + pkgs).stdout.flush()



File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 100
nstall (pkgs) : try : try : from pip._internal import main except Exception: from pip import main except ImportError: error_no_pip() return main([ 'install' ] + pkgs) def do_uninstall (pkgs) : try : try : from pip._internal import main except Exception: from pip import main except ImportError: error_no_pip() return main([ 'uninstall' , '-y' ] + pkgs).stdout.flush()
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I did everything installed pip/pip3 again. Also tried to edit nstall to install on line 100. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Setting--> project interpreter -->[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3KNd.png) --> search flask --> install

Comment: + sign is disabled.